# Formula for total time of flight of a projectile

Tags: kinematics

We know that at maximum height of a projectile only horizontal velocity exists.If 'u' be the initial velocity of the projectile and x be the angle of projection ....then is the following relation correct?

$$u \cos x = u - gt $$

or:

$$u - u\cos x=gt $$

or:

$$ t=u(1-\cos x)/g $$

$$T=2t=2u(1-cos x)/g $$

Comment: I can't make sense of your first equation. For one thing, $u$ and $x$, hence $u$ and $u \cos x$, are constants set by the initial launch; how can you sensibly equate  $u-u \cos x$ to the variable $gt$ ?

Comment: I used the equation v=u-at,where v=ucos x(at maximum height).

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote it, the first relation, $u \cos x = u - gt$ is not really correct, because $u$ cannot denote a vector and a scalar at the same time. What would hold is
$$
|\vec u| \cos x = | \vec u - \vec g t|~,
$$
where $\vec g$ points upwards. Making the vectors and their absolute values explicit in this way, you can also immediately see that you cannot rearrange the equation the way you did, because in general $|\vec u - \vec g t| \neq |\vec u| - |\vec g| t$.

A common way to calculate the total time a mass point needs to reach the same height it started from again when launched at velocity $\vec u$ would be:

- Parameterise the trajectory $\vec r(t)$ as a parabola,
  $$
      \vec r(t) = \vec u t - g t^2 \vec e_z~,
    $$
  with $\vec e_z$ as the vertical unit vector (pointing upwards). Here, I also assumed that $\vec r(0) = \vec 0$.
- Extract the $z$-component by multiplying with $\vec e_z$,
  $$
  r_z(t) = \vec u \vec e_z t - gt^2~.
  $$
- Solve $r_z(t) = 0$ for $t$. One solution is obviously $r_z(0) = 0$, which is the starting point. The other solution will give you the desired point in time.

*Remark:* With $x$ as you defined it, $\vec u \vec e_z = |\vec u| \sin x$.